# Convert ext3 image to qcow2 format

Tags: virtual-machine, qemu, libvirt

I have an ext3 image. But I need image in qcow2 format to bring up the VM using qemu. Is there any command to create qcow2 from ext3 format?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assumptions:

- QEMU already installed
- "ext3 format" is an image of a HDD ext3 partition e.g. created by dd (probably really a raw file)

  qemu-img convert -O qcow2 image.ext3 image.qcow2

Answer (score 1):

My improvised method:

- Create a qcow2 image disk with enough space to accommodate the ext3 image.

  ```
  qemu-img create -f qcow2 disk.qcow2 10G
  ```
- Expose the qcow2 image as a device.

  ```
  modprobe nbd
  qemu-nbd -c /dev/nbd0 disk.qcow2
  ```
- Create a linux partition inside the qcow2 disk.

  ```
  cfdisk /dev/nbd0
  ```
- Copy the the ext3 image over the linux partition.

  ```
  dd if=image.ext3 of=/dev/nbd0p1
  ```
- Disconnect the qcow2 device.

  ```
  sync
  qemu-nbd -d /dev/nbd0
  ```

Ready! :)